# "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'x' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF" - inserting record with nested custom object

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I get the error "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'UserPermission' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF" trying to insert a record as follows:

```
dbContext.User.Add(someUser);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

That being said, the User file has the custom class UserPermission as one of its parameters, and `someUser`'s UserPermission is not null and has a set ID parameter. Why does this happen and is it possible to avoid getting this error without having to explicitly add a UserPermissionID foreign key parameter in my User model and setting the UserPermission parameter to null?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue typically happens when deserializing entities that have related entities in the object graph then attempting to add them. UserPermission is likely an existing record that in the DB is set up with an identity PK, but EF doesn't appear to recognize that in the entity definition. (I.e. set to `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)`. If it had been you would most likely be seeing a different problem where a completely new duplicate UserPermission was being created.

If someUser, and it's associated someUser.UserPermission are deserialized entities then you need to do a bit of work to ensure EF is aware that UserPermission is an existing row:

```
void AddUser(User someUser)
{
    var existingPermission = _context.UserPermissions.Local
        .SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserPermissionId == someUser.UserPermission.UserPermissionId);
    if (existingPermission != null)
        someUser.UserPermission = existingPermission;
    else
        _context.Attach(someUser.UserPermission);

    _context.Users.Add(someUser);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

In a nutshell, when working with detached entities that a DbContext may not be tracking, we need to check the `Local` state for any existing tracked instance for that ID. If we find one, we substitute the detached reference for the tracked one. If we don't find one, we attach the detached one before Adding our user.

This still isn't *entirely* safe because it assumes that the referenced UserPermission **will** exist in the database. If for any reason a non-existent UserPermission is sent in (row deleted, or fake data) you will get an exception on Save.

Passing detached entity references around can seem like a simple option at first, but you need to do this for *every* reference within a detached entity. If you simply call `Attach` without first checking, it will likely work until you come across a scenario where at runtime it doesn't work because the context happens to already be tracking an instance.